# Getting "No Signal" on monitor when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-installation

I have a Windows 10 OS now and I want to install Ubuntu on it with my bootable USB that has Ubuntu installed on it. When I start the computer and I click F8 to bring up the menu to select what I want to choose. I chose my USB drive and the Ubuntu screen shows up. After about 10 seconds the monitor turns of and says "No Signal", just like when it's not plugged in to the computer.

The bootable USB works, because today I installed it on two different computers and it worked perfectly.

These are my computer specs. I'm guessing it has to do something with the graphics card, but not sure what it is.

[image: CPU and GPU]
[image: OS and BIOS]

Comment: [Related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you select booting from the LiveUSB and the screen blanks, start tapping the letter 'e' and soon you will see the [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) (also see [II](https://opensource.com/article/17/3/introduction-grub2-configuration-linux) and [III](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)) commands which start Ubuntu. Replace *quiet splash* with *nomodeset* to bypass the video adapter problem.